# Why did cloud foundry move from DEA to diego

Tags: cloud-foundry

Any relevant information or links.

This is asked as a further explanation from what was given in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OkmVTFhfLY

I was able to find the differences but did not understand the challenges faced with DEA.
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/diego/dea-vs-diego.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest reason is "Warden could only manage containers on VMs running Linux, but the Garden subsystem supports VMs running diverse operating systems. "

I have used PCF more than OSS CF. DEA supported only linux workloads. Diego supports linux and windows workloads.

In the SpringOne conference that concluded today, they announced support for Ubuntu Xenial and MS Windows 1803 (latest windows server). Take a look at [Onsi Fakhouri's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ezNJvajUU0) for new features.

Also please go thru these ...

- https://content.pivotal.io/blog/pivotal-people-onsi-fakhouri-the-science-of-diego
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-design-notes

As to Garden, it is the GO rewrite of the Warden container manager. Garden is more optimized and faster and supports Garden-runC, and Garden-Windows.

Comment: DEA's are ancient history at this point. Back when the conversion happened, they were already showing their age. Diego was a chance to rewrite, re-architect and generally make the platform way better. I would say that the main take away is that Diego is better in every way. It runs buildpacks, it runs docker images, it makes it easier to integrate other OS's and it's way faster and more scaleable.